# Explainer dashboard index not in sync across other components (inside a tab) when selected from drop down

Tags: python, dashboard, lightgbm

I am using https://explainerdashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to show/explain the predicted results from my lightgbm classification model.
I am able to deploy and run it fine. But, inside a particular tab(lets take 'Individual Predictions' as example), when I click dropdown on the index, I have three issues:

1. It doesn't show all the values unless I type something in the search box. Then it lists all values.
2. It doesn't search the typed values in search box correctly. The words just disappear after I type something.
3. Most importantly, the index value selected from the drop down of one component doesn't show the same index name across all components. It is getting filtered across components but still shows old index name on the other components. (But, if i click random index button it seems to show the right index across all components)

Any tips/suggestion welcome or is it just another unfixed bug in the library?

(If anybody could tag 'explainerdashboard' then that would be a great help)